# Use input text box value to search through Movie reviews API AJAX Method- JS

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, api

I am very new to JS and I have a problem to create a searchable movie reviewer html page, it is very basic, I just want to know how to have the input box search the NYT API for the movie I am looking for, I wont have a problem putting the elements onto the page, I just want to know how to search properly. I expect I need a function that when the search button is clicked it requests from the site all movies with the words provided.

```html
<div id="search">
    <input type="text" id = "search">
    <button onclick="search()">Search</button>
</div>

<textarea id="APIoutput" cols="90" rows="50"></textarea>
```

```js
const ISFINISHED = 4;
const ISOK = 200;
var searchedMovie = document.getElementById("search").value;

function getJSONSync(url){
    var response = "";
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if(xmlHttp !== null){
    
        xmlHttp.open("GET", url, false);
        xmlHttp.send(null);
        response = xmlHttp.responseText;
    
    }
    return response;
} 

function getJSONAsync(url, callback) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState === ISFINISHED && request.status === ISOK) {
            callback(this);
        }
    };
    request.open("GET", url);
    request.send();
}

function search(searchedMovie){
    var my_api_url = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/movies/v2/reviews/search.json?query=" + searchedMovie + "&api-key=" + API;

    return my_api_url;
}

function handleAPIresponse(response) {
    var textArea = document.getElementById("APIoutput");
    textArea.value = response.responseText;
}

getJSONAsync(my_api_url, handleAPIresponse);
```

ERRORS: Uncaught ReferenceError: my_api_url is not defined

> Expected Results: (UNFORMATTED JSON THAT LOOKS LIKE THIS:)
> {"status":"OK","copyright":"Copyright (c) 2021 The New York Times
> Company. All Rights
> Reserved.","has_more":false,"num_results":10,"results":[{"display_title":"The
> Black Godfather","mpaa_rating":"TV-MA","critics_pick":0,"byline":"BEN
> KENIGSBERG","headline":"‘The Black Godfather’ Review: The Music
> Executive Who Made It All Happen"

Comment: Build the URL with the text box value within your `search` function. `var searchedMovie = document.getElementById("search").value` runs only once when you script is first evaluated and the input value is empty

Comment: @Phil Thank you for replying, i needed any help I could get! I already tried that, however, I had it like this
 function search(searchedMovie){
  var my_api_url = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/movies/v2/reviews/search.json?query=" + searchedMovie + "&api-key=" + API;
            
            return my_api_url;
        }
getJSONAsync(my_api_url, handleAPIresponse);

Comment: Please update the code in your question to match and explain what the problems are. Do you see any errors reported in your browser console?

Comment: @Phil updated. Errors at bottom above expected result

Comment: You should be calling `getJSONAsync(my_api_url, handleAPIresponse)` inside your `search` function after defining `my_api_url`

Comment: @Phil And what do I do with my handleAPIresponse function? Put it above or also in the search function somehow?

Comment: No, it's fine where it is. FYI code is a lot easier to read and comprehend if your indents are correct. I suggest using an IDE / editor that supports code formatting

Comment: @Phil I have 0 results, not sure what to do. Also I do use an IDE, i dont know if its the best but its called Brackets, and I always have a hard time putting code on Stackoverflow, thats the reason its messed.

Comment: _"I have 0 results"_... is that unexpected for the search value? Any errors in the console now? How about the _Network_ panel; can you see the request being made? If so, does it have the correct parameters? What is the response?

Comment: @Phil Yes unexpected, Im testing the same word that works when hardcoded into the API request "Godfather". I see now from the network, the api call search value is "undefined" (search.json?query=undefined), when it should be godfather(search.json?query=godfather). No errors in console, something is definetly wrong, either parameters or something else. The response is "{"status":"OK","copyright":"Copyright (c) 2021 The New York Times Company. All Rights Reserved.","has_more":false,"num_results":0,"results":null}"

Comment: Oh, I missed it earlier. You need to get the value of the input box within `search`. Like I said in my first comment, you're only getting the value once when the field is empty